# GetAllNetworkInterfaces() throws exception

Tags: c#, android, networking, mono, xamarin.android

In Mono for Android I'm trying to obtain all the IP addresses for my device within the local network.

I don't mind loopbacks but I'm not interested in calling DNS.

The best way seems to be calling...

```
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

NetworkInterface[] adapters = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
```

...except it throws...

> System.EntryPointNotFoundException: getifaddrs

Any suggestions?

Comment: put all the stack trace of your exception, i think that you should declare a permission of access NETWORK or NETWORK_STATE or something like this

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately this is a known bug in Mono for Android. The bug report is available [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1969).

Comment: Unbelievably, it's still happening in latest alpha version OCT 2013.

Comment: And the same is happening in MAY 2014.

Answer (score 0):

If you only use Mono for Android, you can try this code to obtain every IP:

```
Java.Util.IEnumeration networkInterfaces = NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaces;
while(networkInterfaces.HasMoreElements) {
    Java.Net.NetworkInterface netInterface = (Java.Net.NetworkInterface)networkInterfaces.NextElement();
    Console.WriteLine(netInterface.ToString());
}
```

Output:

> [lo][1][/::1%1%1][/127.0.0.1]
>   [dummy0][2]
>   [sit0][3]
>   [ip6tnl0][4]
>   [wlan0][5][/fe80::8e77:12ff:fe5a:6052%wlan0%5][/192.168.100.135]
>   [ppp0][6][/10.0.0.1]